# This page is insecure (broken HTTPS) on my Tumblr Blog

Tags: css, tumblr, yahoo

Immature CSS coder here, basically only know how to deal with CSS on tumblr blogs. A novel problem, when I finished editing [this blog](http://Haued.tumblr.com), it returns that this page is insecure (broken HTTPS), and fails to load up any of the scripts I can, including pop up links. These pop ups don't redirect to any other site than the blog itself, so the fact it's failing to show the popups is problematic.

I looked into it and this was perhaps the error it is returning that makes it insecure:

> global.build.js?_v=06d02b5…:25 GET https://fc.yahoo.com/sdarla/php/client.php?f=1197719150 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

But I have no way to access this site or anything related, and not sure how I am able to fix this through it.

If it helps, here's the code for the blog: http://pastebin.com/8wz9XWKB

Comment: When you load http stuff on a https page, the https page is no longer fully secure. Look for http elements like jquery and fonts on the page, update those to use https and you are good to go.
You might need to edit the theme or something though. Not very familiar with customizing Tumblr.

Answer (score 0):

Go into your blog settings and ensure this is disabled.

[image: photo of relevant setting]

Tumblr has recently made it so that all new blogs automatically have this option enabled, which is rather silly considering even they say:

> "Try it, and if it makes your Tumblr look funny, just come back and
>   disable it."